# Laravel 5.0 - Error by running composer install

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

On Ubuntu, when I clone my Laravel 5.0 project from GitHub and then hit "composer install", I get the following result:

[image]

I can't see the .env file, but I tried copying .env file from other local project and then I get one error loading blade files using @include():

[image]

I tried on Windows too, but is the same result, I notice when I do "git add --all" a warnning message is showed:

[image]

Comment: Does the file /opt/lampp/htdocs/teachme2016/resources/views/tickets/list.blade.php exist on your system? This is definitely not a composer problem, but either a git problem (the file has not been commited and pushed) or a mistake on your side.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Yes, It does in the path, but I don't know what happend yet.

Comment: You probably cloned Laravel framework and not the complete Laravel package. Follow installation instructions on Laravel.com, you can install Laravel by by using composer or Laravel install...

Comment: Thanks @Digitlimit, I changed the entry adding the git problem that I've seen. Please look up the change, I don't know why this happend or whether has some relation.

Comment: One of the last lines of your `composer install` output is `Writing lock file`, which is strange because you are supposed to commit this file into the repository. If it is missing, Composer will act like an `update` when installing, i.e. it will fetch the newest matching versions. This can mess things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, when I run "chmod -R 775 project_name", I had some views errors like:

[image]

I fixed the problem changing view path from this "tickets\partials\status" to "tickets/partials/status". I never thought that was the problem, because on Windows run right with this: "tickets\partials\status".